# SpringBoot with circleci: error: /bin/bash: docker: command not found

Tags: docker, circleci, circleci-workflows

Creating Docker image failed because I didn't install Docker Client on CircleCi environment.

The official CircleCi document only provided the Go version of install Docker Client, but my project is build in with jdk-14.0.2

Here is my config.yml file example:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: openjdk:14.0.2-jdk-slim

    # make working directory on circleCI
    working_directory: ~/upload-image

    steps:
      # git pull
      - checkout

      # setup testing env
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 19.03.13
          docker_layer_caching: true
      ### I believe I should install docker-cli here via jdk not via apk, but I don't know how to  ###
      #      - run:          
      #          name: Install Docker client
      #          command: apk add docker-cli
     
      # the error occurs at this step since the docker-cli is not installed
      - run:
          name: doese Docker Exist
          command: docker -v
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem solved, needs to install docker cli in the environment. Or the simple way is using a language image that has the docker cli pre-installed, for example: `- image: cimg/openjdk:14.0`